# Ubuntu SDK for x86 tablets

Tags: intel, tablet, ubuntu-sdk

I was thinking about installing the regular Ubuntu on a Windows 8 tablet with x86 processor...so basically a tablet that is actually a PC. I want to make a program that supports all gestures and movement detection of a tablet. Windows 8 has full support on a variety of different programming languages and supports all mobile device sensors in its SDK. I am not sure about Ubuntu.

So my question is: Is there a Ubuntu SDK that supports all features of a x86 tablet? I am not interested in ARM tablets.

Thx for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu touch is not yet available for x86, But you can expect it in near future